# Handling documentID in FirebaseFirestoreSwift is really confusing

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have to query a slew of collections and the models are always defined something like this:

```
struct Order : Identifiable, Codable {

    @DocumentID var id : String?
    
    let fieldOne : String?
    let fieldTwo : Int?

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id // (had to comment this out)
        case fieldOne
        case fieldTwo
    }
}
```

Today, I spent all day trying to figure out why I couldn't load documents from for one particular collection. I was getting a snapshot with documents but could not convert and populate them into an array. After hours of trial and error I commented out the "case id" in the enum and got it to work.

Any idea why this is happening?

Here's a query which works WITH the case id:

```
listener = db.collection("Meal_Plans").whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userEmail).order(by: "timeOfCreation", descending: true).addSnapshotListener({ (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error in mp query: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No mealplans")
                    return
                }
                let mealplanArray: [Mealplan] = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Mealplan? in
                  return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Mealplan.self)
                }
                let planViewModel = mealplanArray.map({return PlanViewModel(mealplan: $0)})
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if mealplanArray.count > 0 {
                        self.planViewModelDelegate?.plansFetched(self.updateHour(sourcePlans: planViewModel))
                    }
                }
            }
    })
```

And this is the one WITHTOUT:

```
listener = db.collection("Placed_Orders").whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId).whereField("status", isLessThan: 410).order(by: "status", descending: false).order(by: "nextOrderDate", descending: false).addSnapshotListener({ (documentSnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error")
                self.orderCallback?(error.localizedDescription, nil, .error)
            } else {
                print("empty")
                guard let documents = documentSnapshot?.documents else {
                    return }
                if documents.isEmpty {
                    self.orderCallback?("No orders found", nil, .error)
                    return
                } else {
                    print("snapshot count: \(documents.count)")
                    let orderArray: [Order] = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Order? in
                      return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Order.self)
                    }
                    let orderViewModel = orderArray.map({ return OrderViewModel(order: $0)})
                    print("array count: \(orderArray.count)")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("status: \(orderViewModel)")
                        self.orderCallback?(nil, orderViewModel, .success)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

The differences are rather subtle. In both cases I am using a snapshot listener to query the snapshot and populate it into an array and then map that array into a view model.

Yet, in the latter case, I have to comment out the case id for the identifiable field. I need the ID so need to see if it's working but would like to know why I have to comment out the case id.